# App to be reminded of dates in a particular sequence?

Tags: web-apps, osx, calendar, reminders

For instance, if I want to be reminded every N numbers of days starting with a particular date, is there an app or category of tools that can accomplish the task?

Comment: Well, we don't recommend categories here – but your (very short) definition smells for a calendar with repeating events, doesn't it? If so, the question is rather whether there's a calendar NOT supporting that :)

Comment: @Izzy you are right, I was't aware of the feature for repeating or recurring events, both Google calendar and the built-in calendar o OS X seem to have it. I'll gladly accept your comment as answer.

Comment: Done! As my wife uses to say: "if it's in front of your nose, you're sure to miss it" #D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not a specific software recommendation, your requirements are met by tons of apps called "calendars" having a feature called "reoccuring events". They'd not only let you define a start date and interval, but an end date as well. Example: "Starting on May 26th, 2017 and until July 28th, 2017, weekly at 11:00pm, remind me to have a break from TV" :)

Sometimes the most obvious and easily available solutions slip through the nets of our brains :)